# Windows 7/10 - Make Application launch on a different display

Tags: c#, linux, windows, vbscript, cmd

I am porting a Linux application to windows , there are two executable's which need to be launched on primary and secondary displays respectively.

In Linux its done through  #!/bin/sh script,something like

display_start_dualhead LVDS 800 480 DVI 1024 768 24
  export screen_main=$LVDS
  export screen_secondary=$DVI

how can this be done in Windows , launching exe1 in monitor 1 and exe 2 in monitor 2 ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Process creation on windows is performed through the [CreateProcess](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682425(v=vs.85).aspx) API which is passed a [STARTUPINFO](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686331(v=vs.85).aspx) struct. This structure allows initial visibility and positional information to be passed to the launched process, with the intention that the process will use this when creating - and showing - its initial window.

I do not know of a built in command line tool that will populate the positional fields with the co-ordinates of each monitor, although the `start` command can be instructed to launch the window maximised or minimized.

Nonetheless it should be a trivial exercise to make an application that enumerates the monitors and fills these fields in. That said - having done this you might just find that the applications ignore these fields and position their windows directly.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
function void showOnMonitor1()
{
    Screen[] sc;
    sc = Screen.AllScreens;
    //get all the screen width and heights
    Form2 f = new Form2();
    f.FormBorderStyle = FormBorderStyle.None;
    f.Left = sc[0].Bounds.Width;
    f.Top = sc[0].Bounds.Height;
    f.StartPosition = FormStartPosition.Manual;
    f.Location = sc[0].Bounds.Location;
    Point p = new Point(sc[0].Bounds.Location.X, sc[0].Bounds.Location.Y);
    f.Location = p;
    f.WindowState = FormWindowState.Maximized;
    f.Show();
}



function void showOnMonitor2()
{
    Screen[] sc;
    sc = Screen.AllScreens;
    //get all the screen width and heights
    Form2 f = new Form2();
    f.FormBorderStyle = FormBorderStyle.None;
    f.Left = sc[1].Bounds.Width;
    f.Top = sc[1].Bounds.Height;
    f.StartPosition = FormStartPosition.Manual;
    f.Location = sc[1].Bounds.Location;
    Point p = new Point(sc[1].Bounds.Location.X, sc[1].Bounds.Location.Y);
    f.Location = p;
    f.WindowState = FormWindowState.Maximized;
    f.Show();
}
```

OR

```
if (System.Windows.Forms.SystemInformation.MonitorCount != 1)
{
            Form form2 = new Form();
            form2.Left = System.Windows.Forms.SystemInformation.PrimaryMonitorSize.Width + 1;
            form2.Top = 0;
            form2.ShowDialog();
 }
```